# Computation with Mayer-Vietoris and fundamental classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional closed oriented connected manifold and suppose that $\bar{U},\bar{V}\subset M$ are $n$-dimensional manifolds with boundary so that $M=\bar{U}\cup \bar{V}$ and $\bar{U}\cap \bar{V}=\partial U=\partial V$.

If we compute Mayer-Vietoris sequence of $(\bar{U},\bar{V}, M)$ then the first non-trivial term looks like
$$
0\to \mathbb{Z}\overset{\delta}\to \mathbb{Z}^N \to \cdots
$$
where $N$ is the number of components of $\partial U=\partial V$.  I'm pretty sure that the map $\delta$ is given algebraically by 
$$1\mapsto (1, \ldots, 1)$$
where here $1$ represents the fundamental class of $M$ and $(1,0,\ldots, 0), \ldots, (0, \ldots, 0, 1)$ are the fundamental classes of the components of $\partial U$.

However, I don't work in topology and so am not completely confident of this.  Is this correct and is there a reference for this sort of material?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you think about $\bar U$ and $\bar V$ as about classes in $C_n(M)$, then $d(\bar U)=-d(\bar V)$ and $\bar U+\bar V$ equals the fundamental class of $M$. So you have $\delta :[M]\mapsto[\partial U]$, and fundamental class of $\partial U$ is the sum of fundamental classes of all components.

For more details i can advice just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence#Unreduced_version

Comment: I understood that part, the part I didn't understand was why $[\partial U]$ was the fundamental class (and not say some integer multiple of it).  Maybe this follows from excision (like I said my background in this is quite week).

Comment: When you identify any submanifold with corresponding homology class, you take this submanifold with coefficient $1$ (if this submanifold is triangulated, then you just have a collection of singular simplices). Submanifold with a boundary is not a cycle, and its chain-boundary coincides with its boundary-as-a-manifold.